# Method calling error

Tags: java, static-methods

I need to use two methods in my program which converts temperatures 
I have a problem with calling my method
here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String unit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter unit F or C: ");

        String temp1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Temperature: ");


        double temp = Double.valueOf(temp1).doubleValue();




        public static double convertTemp(){
         if((unit.equals("F"))||(unit.equals("f"))){
        double c= (temp - 32) / 1.8;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c+" Celsius"));
        }

         else if((unit.equals("C"))||(unit.equals("c"))){
        double f=((9.0 / 5.0) * temp) + 32.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f+" Fahrenheit");

}
}
}
```

Comment: Don't just say "I have a problem". Please explain what exactly the problem is. Do you get an error message? Then copy & paste the error message. Does the program give you some answer that's different from what you expected? Then tell us what you expected and how the actual output differs from this.

Comment: if this is homework please tag it...

Comment: Is this syntactically correct ?

Comment: There is still an error which is illegal start of a expression

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static double {
         if((unit.equals("F"))||(unit.equals("f"))){
        double c= (temp - 32) / 1.8;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c+" Celsius");
        }
```

is not valid Java.  You need to create a method, outside the main method

```
public static double convertTemp(){
...
}
```

you will have to add arguments to the method call (between the `()`).

To be clear, your file should look like

```
public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      ....
    }

    public static double convertTemp(){
      ....
    }
}
```

of course, the meat of the code goes inside the method declarations.

Comment: And without the method name or parameter list, to boot.

Comment: @Dave are you saying my answer is incomplete, or elaborating on the errors in OP code?

Comment: I keep getting an error: Illegal start of expression:

Comment: @user1190386 update your question with the full code AND the error.  Remove the checkmark from this answer until the question is actually answered.

Comment: The errors are: Illegal start of an expression & Cannot find symbol