# Missing return statement

Tags: java

I am getting the following errors in my code: 
-Missing return statement
-Cannto find symbol in the second method

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String unit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter unit F or C: ");

        String temp1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Temperature: ");


        double temp = Double.valueOf(temp1).doubleValue();
    }




        public static double convertTemp(){
         if((unit.equals("F"))||(unit.equals("f"))){
        double c= (temp - 32) / 1.8;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c+" Celsius"));
        }

         else if((unit.equals("C"))||(unit.equals("c"))){
        double f=((9.0 / 5.0) * temp) + 32.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f+" Fahrenheit");

}
}
}
```

Comment: And what is unclear about the error telling you that you don't have a return statement ... when you don't have a return statement?

Comment: You [already have a question open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771136/method-calling-error).

Answer (score 4):

Your convertTemp method has a return type of double. Your setting the value on the JOptionPane, but you aren't returning it from the method. You have two options here:

1) Don't set the value on JOptionPane inside of convertTemp. Instead return the value and set the JOptionPane value in your main method

```
public static double convertTemp() {
    double c = 0.0;
    /* do stuff */
    return c;
}
```

2) Change the method to return void:

```
public static void convertTemp() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return `double` and there is no return statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your return statement for the convertTemp() function?

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration says you return a double, but then you dont return anything.

```
public static double convertTemp(){
```

Just change that to return void;

```
public static void convertTemp(){
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're going to do in a function is display a message dialog, it should be of type void. You do not assign the variable "f" to anything when you call convertTemp, e.g.

```
double x = convertTemp()
```

so it should be declared void, just like your main function.

Also, how are you getting "temp" to your convertTemp function? You need to either declare it as part of your class outside of a function, or pass it to convertTemp, like this:

```
convertTemp(double temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static double convertTemp(){
     if((unit.equals("F"))||(unit.equals("f"))){
         double c= (temp - 32) / 1.8;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c+" Celsius"));
         return c;   //add this
     }

     else if((unit.equals("C"))||(unit.equals("c"))){
        double f=((9.0 / 5.0) * temp) + 32.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f+" Fahrenheit");
        return f;    //add this
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated the method would return a `double` that's why a return statement is required. Either change the return type to `void` (if you don't need the returned value) or add the statements like below :

```
public static double convertTemp(){

  if((unit.equals("F"))||(unit.equals("f"))){
    double c= (temp - 32) / 1.8;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c+" Celsius"));

    //return c here
    return c;
  }

  else if((unit.equals("C"))||(unit.equals("c"))){
    double f=((9.0 / 5.0) * temp) + 32.0;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,f+" Fahrenheit");

    //
    return f;
  }

  // return 0 - or something else - when neither f nor c where selected
  return 0.0;
}
```